# Get the containing folder of a file

Tags: rust, path, filesystems

I am trying to extract the containing folder of a file in Rust. Is there any way to go from a `String` to getting the containing folder? For example, the following code works, however it is messy:

```
let path = "/path/to/file.txt";

let mut path_arr: Vec<&str> = path.split('/').collect();
path_arr.pop();

let new_string = path_arr.join("/");

assert_eq!("/path/to", new_string);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are built-in types, `Path` and `PathBuf` for this:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

let path = PathBuf::from("/path/to/file.txt");
let dir = path.parent().unwrap();

assert_eq!("/path/to", dir.to_str().unwrap());
```

You don't usually need to convert a `Path` or `PathBuf` back to a `&str` or `String`, as I have done above, because most of the `std` APIs will accept them directly.